# Is there are way to add measures from a custom connector?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have created a custom connector for Power BI. Now, I would like that also the connector add measures. Is it possible?  There are more than 200 measures and it is not viable to do it manually.

Comment: Check this link- https://exceleratorbi.com.au/copy-measures-between-2-power-bi-files/

Comment: Conector is one thing, data model is another. I recommend you read this great blog post:
[What is a Power BI Data Model](https://exceleratorbi.com.au/what-is-a-power-bi-data-model/)

Comment: Thanks R_R, Tabular Editor is the solution for me!